# Displaying error messages to users in web application

Tags: javascript, html

I'm developing a web app and for the login system, there are two types of errors the user can get. Right now it only displays that error to the console as seen in the picture. I'm using a firebase login system and I want it to display in an alert box when the error is caught. Any help would be greatly appreciated!
Error message:
  https://i.stack.imgur.com/hHKL2.jpg

Comment: Can you provide the code?

Comment: wrap your code (if suitable) in javascript try/catch block and display your own custom message.

Answer (score 0):

```
const handleLogin = () => { Firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email,password).catch((error) => alert(error))};
```